# How to make IDEA recognise keywords from Jasmine Node.js package?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I've got an IDEA 14.1.2 project using the Jasmine Node module for testing. Unfortunately **IDEA doesn't recognise Jasmine function names** like `beforeEach`, `describe`, `it` and `expect`, even though everything seems valid (the tests run fine). That is, when hovering over any of these I get a message like "Unresolved function or method function_name()", and when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-clicking I get the message "Cannot find declaration to go to".

Relevant settings:

1. In Languages & Frameworks → JavaScript → Libraries the following are checked:

   - Node.js v0.12.2 Core Modules (type Global)
   - HTML (type Predefined)
   - HTML5 / ECMAScript 5 (type Predefined)
   - Node.js Globals (type Predefined)
2. In Languages & Frameworks → Node.js and NPM (NodeJS JetBrains plugin 141.712):

   - the Node interpreter is set (it's in a subdirectory of the project),
   - "Node.js v0.12.2 Core Modules is set up", and
   - under Packages "jasmine" is listed as version 2.2.1 (latest).

Maybe I need to [index internal Node modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/installing-and-removing-external-software-using-node-package-manager.html#d58881e658), but I don't have the relevant check box in Languages & Frameworks → Node.js and NPM. Is this not available in this version of the plugin?

I've tried invalidating caches and restarting.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a TypeScript definition file as described [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/).

Go to `Project Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries`, click `Download`, select `Typescript community stubs` from the combobox, choose `jasmine` and click `Download and Install`.

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm puzzled why it should be necessary. After all, the source is already available and recognised as a dependency.